# PIP installing globally instead of virtual env

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I normally code in R, but I am having to learn Python for a project and am struggling to get the environment set up. The issue I seem to be having is that I am unable to get packages to install into the environment, instead the are installing globally. I assume I have a setting wrong or something somewhere.

I checked that I am running pip from the venv and it seems to be.

```
(venv) Johns-MacBook-Pro:venv johncarty$ which pip
/Users/johncarty/Documents/VGP/pythonProject/venv/bin/pip
```

When I run

```
pip install dash
```

I get the following output on everything pip tries to install.

```
WARNING: Target directory /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dash_html_components already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
```

Edit to add output of `pip debug --verbose`

```
(venv) Johns-MacBook-Pro:pythonProject johncarty$ pip debug --verbose
WARNING: This command is only meant for debugging. Do not use this with automation for parsing and getting these details, since the output and options of this command may change without notice.
pip version: pip 21.1.2 from /Users/johncarty/Documents/VGP/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
sys.version: 3.7.2 (v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 24 2018, 02:44:43) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
sys.executable: /Users/johncarty/Documents/VGP/pythonProject/venv/bin/python
sys.getdefaultencoding: utf-8
sys.getfilesystemencoding: utf-8
locale.getpreferredencoding: UTF-8
sys.platform: darwin
sys.implementation:
    name: cpython
'cert' config value: global
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: None
CURL_CA_BUNDLE: None
pip._vendor.certifi.where(): /Users/johncarty/Documents/VGP/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/certifi/cacert.pem
pip._vendor.DEBUNDLED: False
vendored library versions:
    appdirs==1.4.4
    CacheControl==0.12.6
    colorama==0.4.4
    distlib==0.3.1
    distro==1.5.0 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
    html5lib==1.1
    msgpack==1.0.2 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
    packaging==20.9
    pep517==0.10.0
    progress==1.5
    pyparsing==2.4.7
    requests==2.25.1
    certifi==2020.12.05
    chardet==4.0.0
    idna==3.1
    urllib3==1.26.4
    resolvelib==0.7.0
    setuptools==44.0.0 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
    six==1.15.0
    tenacity==7.0.0 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
    toml==0.10.2
    webencodings==0.5.1 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
Compatible tags: 1336
```

Comment: In the terminal where you have activated your virtual environment. Is this where you are running your `pip install` command?

Comment: Any chance of you running `pip install` in some other terminal which the venv is not activated?

Comment: I don't think so. I only have one instance of PyCharm open, and no native terminals open.

Comment: An idea could be re creating the project. Maybe it's something about project's settings.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure you can use absolute paths:

```
/Users/johncarty/Documents/VGP/pythonProject/venv/bin/pip install dash
```

If you will be working on that project for a while, activate the virtual environment:

```
/Users/johncarty/Documents/VGP/pythonProject/venv/Scripts/activate.bat
```

or look for the `activate.bat` script in the above *virtual env* tree

Comment: This still tried to install globally.

Comment: Please add the output of `pip debug` and installing it with `--verbose`

Comment: Added an edit to the main post with this info.