# venv is installing packages globally

Tags: python, bash, python-venv

I have fresh compiled version of *CPython*, 3.12, and wanted to start a new project in a new virtual environment with `venv`.

I noticed that each time I install a package inside my virtual environment it is *not* going to be installed inside my project directory but in the global directory `/home/USER_NAME/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/`.

I read many posts on related problems but I couldn't find anything useful and just start to confuse me... an installation inside a virtual environment should be local to the environment itself, right? I already tried to delete the environment and create a new one again but got the same result, I cannot figure out what's wrong.

I can provide further technical details such as `pip debug`, configurations or environment variables if needed.

My system is updated and have different versions (3.9, 3.11, 3.12) of Python.

---

Here some details of the issue

1. Check packages of the global installation

```bash
$ python -m pip list
Package Version
------- -------
pip     23.3.1
```

2. Create new virtual environment in the target directory

```bash
$ python -m venv ./myenv
```

3. Activate the environment

```bash
$ source ./myenv/bin/activate
```

4. installing a package

```
(myenv) $ python -m pip install pypdf
```

5. check installation

```
(myenv) $ python -m pip list
Package Version
------- -------
pip     23.3.1
pypdf   3.17.1
```

6. exit the virtual environment

```bash
(myvenv) $ deactivate
```

7. Checking again global installation

```bash
$ python -m pip list
Package Version
------- -------
pip     23.3.1
pypdf   3.17.1   # <-
```

---

**EDIT**

Information about the

- system

```py
import platform
uname = platform.uname()
for attr in ['system', 'release', 'version', 'machine']:
    print(f"{attr:<12} {getattr(uname, attr)}")

system       Linux
release      5.10.0-26-amd64
version      #1 SMP Debian 5.10.197-1 (2023-09-29)
machine      x86_64
```

- terminal

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

- Python version (with the issue)

```bash
$ python --version
Python 3.12.0
```

---

Summary from the comments

- `$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"`
  is pointing the the same executable for both: `/home/USER_NAME/PATH/Python-3.12.0/python`
- `which python` is not pointing to the same location for both (for `venv` seems ok)

  - `$ which python` -> `/usr/bin/python # it's Python 2.7.18`
  - `(myenv) $ which python` -> `/home/USER_NAME/PATH/myenv/bin/python`

Comment: You missed a step: Demonstrating that pypdf wasn't already installed before you started.

Comment: (You could also compare `python -c 'import pypdf; print(pypdf.__file__)'` before and after the `deactivate` as a way to demonstrate the same thing, which might also as a side effect give some hints about what's going wrong by letting us see _where_ the installation is taking place).

Comment: The output is the same before and after the quitting the venv, `/home/USER_NAME/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pypdf/__init__.py`

Comment: Also (re)repeated the experiment by uninstalling the package + test as suggested in the comments, but the issue persists

Comment: I used `pypdf` as sample because it is relative lightweight but it happens the same with other packages

Comment: Show us the output of `which python` while the venv is activated.

Comment: `(myenv) $ which python` ->  `/home/USER_NAME/PATH/myenv/bin/python` (correct location)

Comment: Try also `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` with and without the venv.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [PIP installing globally instead of virtual env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71429824/pip-installing-globally-instead-of-virtual-env)

Comment: Please post your exact version of python (`python --version`)  so people could try to reproduce the issue. Does this occur only on the Python 3.12 you've compiled yourself? What is your OS and which type of terminal you're using?

Comment: test repeated with my previous `python3.11` and works as expected, so no problems.

Comment: @Niko Fohr _only_ by explicitly calling `pip` and `python` generated by `venv` with a relative path solve the problem, i,e `(myenv) $ ./myenv/bin/pip install pypdf`, the installation is _really_ local to the virtual environment. The behaviour is still different from the expected one, what could be the reason of that?

Comment: Shell aliases or shell functions being defined that override PATH lookup is the most obvious cause given that symptom. What does `type python` or `type pip` return?

Comment: `type python` -> `python is aliased to `/home/USER/PATH_GIT/Python-3.12.0/python`

Comment: @Charles Duffy I think you touched a good point. In my `.bashrc` I have an alias for the path of `python3.12`

Comment: There's your problem, then; that alias overrides anything the virtualenv activate script might otherwise try to configure.

Comment: Ah! But then how should I configure `python3.12` to call it without its full path and without interfering with `venv`?

Comment: `PATH=/home/USER/PATH_GIT/Python-3.12.0/:$PATH` in your dotfiles would be one way to do that.

Comment: (btw, it's more common to have a `$HOME/bin` directory for personal binaries, or to just wholesale switch to a package manager that permits different users/projects/etc to have different software sets like [Nix](https://nixos.org/); also, going the Nix route means you no longer need pip again for anything, since it can manage Python packages [and node packages, and ruby packages, and... etc, etc, etc] just the same as it manages any other kind of package).

Comment: You had an alias for `python`, but `which python` did not show that alias?  That is surprising.

Comment: I removed the alias, updated the `PATH` variable accordingly and when I run `python`... it prompts to `Python 2.7.18`!, otherwise with `python3` it opens `Python 3.9.2 `. Both are located in `/usr/bin/`. My full `PATH` looks like `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/sbin:$HOME/PATH_GIT/Python-3.12.0/`, even typing `python3.12` won't open it, got `command not found`

Comment: @JohnGordon, not surprising at all. `which` is only a builtin in zsh; everywhere else it's just an external binary that knows nothing about aliases, shell functions, or any other internal state. The POSIX-standard equivalent to what you're used to in zsh is `command -v`, the bash-specific version is `type`.

Comment: @cards, again, put a symlink to the Python that you _want_ to be default in a directory in your PATH. And it needs to be your _actual_ HOME directory, not the string `$HOME`, and at the **beginning** of your PATH, not the end. If you'd followed the example I gave you earlier without any changes whatsoever (no extra quotes or escaping, and the old `$PATH` at the end instead of the beginning) it would have worked.

Comment: Thank you all for the support, by updating the `PATH` variable with the location of the executable it worked